# custom product options,there price is dependent on another?

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way to create custom product options in a way that the one's price is dependent on another (without using the configurable product) ? and i'm using only custom options.

Like for example we have product that have a custom option **Print Type** a radio input having some options [A-Type, B-Type, C-Type] and one more option **Sizes** [XXX,XX,X,L,X,S].

**And my question:** If we change Print Type, the price of **Sizes** should reflect according to the selected **Print Type**. Should i have to use a observer to bind option prices to each other or any other method??